# Differential operator "interior" to a hypersurface?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In eq. (12) of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.5625.pdf) paper a differential operator on two $d+2$ dimensional vector spaces (with coordinates $X^A$ and $W^A$ respectively, $A=1,2,...,d+2$) is defined:

[image]

In the paragraph below it, the authors say that the differential operator was constructed to be "interior" with respect to the sub-manifold $X\cdot X+1=W\cdot W=X\cdot W=0$ (i.e. its action on a function only depends on the value of the function on this submanifold).

While intuitively their description about what the operator is makes sense, it is not clear to me which explicit mathematical constraints were used to construct it such that it is "interior" to the submanifold. Essentially, my question is:

*What is the mathematical formulation of "its action on a function only depends on the value of the function on this submanifold" as a set of constraints on an initially completely generic second order differential operator $K_A^{init}$ acting on the two vector spaces?*

Comment: Possibly a dumb comment, but if we're given a function $K : (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow C$, a reasonably definition is that the value of $K$ depends only on $A' \subseteq A$ iff for all $f,g : A \rightarrow B$, we have that $$f = g \;\mathrm{on}\; A' \rightarrow K(f)=K(g).$$

Comment: @goblin This certainly sounds reasonable. But does it tell us how to construct $K$ ...?